# No connections allowed from your IP

Tags: java, android, ftp

**Error**

```
06-20 12:03:36.630 23124-23124/com.example.admin.demoasync W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5839)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1113)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:879)
    java.lang.IllegalStateException: Client not connected
        at it.sauronsoftware.ftp4j.FTPClient.disconnect(FTPClient.java:1123)
        at com.example.admin.demoasync.Main4Activity.uploadFile(Main4Activity.java:66)
        at com.example.admin.demoasync.Main4Activity$2.onClick(Main4Activity.java:46)
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4848)
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:20300)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:815)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:104)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:210)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5839)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1113)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:879)

it.sauronsoftware.ftp4j.FTPException [code=550, message= No connections allowed from your IP]
```

**Code**

```
public void uploadFile(File fileName)
    {
        FTPClient client = new FTPClient();
        try
        {
            client.connect(FTP_HOST,21);
            client.login(FTP_USER, FTP_PASS);
            client.setType(FTPClient.TYPE_BINARY);
            client.changeDirectory("/PODTrack/Photo/");
            client.upload(fileName, new MyTransferListener());
        } catch (Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
            try
            {
                client.disconnect(true);
            } catch (Exception e2)
            {
                e2.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
```

Our IP is not blocked. I can access it through another FTP client.

Comment: Maybe device/emulator uses different IP ;)

Comment: *"I can access it through other FTP client"* - Does the client run on the same machine as your Java code + Do you use the same username in the *"other FTP client"*?

Answer (score 0):

Look at the stacktrace carefully.  See what method is throwing the exception?  It is `disconnect`!

What is happening is that *something* in your `try` block is throwing *some* exception.  You are catching that exception, and trying to disconnect the connection.  But the `disconnect()` call is failing, and the message says that it is failing because the `client` was not connected (!)

So, either the earlier `client.connect(...)` call failed, or something after that call has disconnected.  (Might a login failure do it?)

The solution will be in two parts:

1. Change

   ```
     client.disconnect(true);
   ```

   to

   ```
     if (client.isConnected()) {
         client.disconnect(true);
     }
   ```

   That will fix the annoying secondary exception that occurs if you call `disconnect()` and the connection is not currently open.
2. Look at the stacktrace for the original exception to see if that gives you any clues.

If the you can access the FTP server using a command-line client on the same IP as your Java code is running, then:

- Check that you are connecting to the right server on the right port.  (I don't think it would be the username and password ... but the stacktrace will tell you!)
- Check that this isn't something to do with your Android Java code and your FTP client using different FTP proxies.  (This would be a possible cause if you were running on a Java (tm) platform, but I don't know for the Android (tm) case.)

Comment: While you are right, I believe that OP stated the root cause correctly: `FTPException [code=550, message= No connections allowed from your IP]`

Comment: @MartinPrikryl - You still need to look at the primary stacktrace to see *where* that message / exception came from.  Fixing the `disconnect` problem allows that.